# Entity Object Not Getting Persisted: New object was found through a relationship that was not marked

Tags: jpa, persistence, eclipselink

I am trying to persist the following entity:

```
public class CommentEntity {

@Id

@ManyToOne(optional=false,cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH, targetEntity=UserEntity.class)
@JoinColumn(name="USERID",referencedColumnName="USERID")
private UserEntity userEntity;

@ManyToOne(optional=false,cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH, targetEntity=PostEntity.class)
@JoinColumn(name="POSTID",referencedColumnName="POSTID")
private PostEntity postEntity;

}
```

But the error comes out:

During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: entity.PostEntity@16afec.

when I try to persist PostEntity, it is persisted. No such exception is thrown:

```
public class PostEntity {

@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = UserEntity.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "USERID", referencedColumnName = "USERID")
private UserEntity userEntity;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "postEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<CommentEntity> commentEntityList;
}
```

Why it is happening? UserEntity is:

```
public class UserEntity {

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userEntity")
private List<PostEntity> postEntityList;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userEntity")
private List<CommentEntity> commentEntityList;
}
```

I am persisting commentEntity using the code:

```
entityManagerFactory = Persistence
                    .createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
            entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
            entityTransaction.begin();
            entityManager.persist(commentEntity);
            entityTransaction.commit();
            entityManager.close();
```

I am not able to understand what can be the cause? And then why PostEntity is getting persisted in the same situation?

I am using EclipseLink

Answer (score 2):

Because you try to persist CommentEntity that have either userEntity or postEntity (or both)  referencing to the entity that is not persisted. Call to *em.persist(instance of commentEntity)* does not cause those entities to be persisted, because you cascaded only refresh. You should persist those entities with separate calls to *em.persist*.

If this does not answer to your question, please provide the code that creates entities and persists them.

Comment: You edited, but are still not showing what the CommentEntity is referencing if anything, when it is persisted. Since it's relations are not set to cascade all, if it is referencing any new entities (such as a new instance of postEntity, they are left unpersisted. While if you persist postEntity, it does cascades over the relationship to the new CommentEntity. Persist all entities before setting the relationships or change your cascade settings so that the persist cascades to all required new entities.