# JPA cascade persist error with an entity that is already persisted

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql, persistence-manager

I've got the error below trying to update an entity. [The solution to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573345/entity-object-not-getting-persisted-new-object-was-found-through-a-relationship) says that the "owned" entity has to be persisted before persisting the owner but I did that. Or to mark both entity with cascade.

error (I guess the full stacktrace isn't needed):

```
2015-08-10T20:45:11.481+0200|Warning: A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB ThreadLookUpService, method: public void main.java.services.ThreadLookUpService.setLastPost(long,main.java.entities.Post)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: main.java.entities.Post@6724f919.
```

( If I add `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` I get another error, telling me that the foreign key doesn't exist but I just persisted it. As far as I understand I shouldn't even have to use cascade if I persist the entities in the right order.

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`forumcs`.`thethreads`, CONSTRAINT `fk_thethreads_posts1` FOREIGN KEY (`last_post`) REFERENCES `posts` (`idpost`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

)

Here I persist post(owned) then Thethread(owner):

```
post = postLookup.createPostAndGiveItBack(post);
threadLookup.setLastPost(thread.getThread().getIdthread(), post); //this gives error.
```

Here is my method to persist post, I used flush because I thought that post id wasn't generated or smtg:

```
@Override
public Post createPostAndGiveItBack(Post post) {
    em.persist(post);
    em.flush();
    return post;
}
```

Here is my method to update the lastPost of Thethread. I could merge it directly with the one I pulled out before but if I did do that then my upvote and downvote field will be messed up if 2 different user watch the same page and update the thread :

```
@Override
public void setLastPost(long id, Post post) {
    Query query = em.createQuery(FIND_THREAD_BY_ID);
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    Thethread thread = (Thethread) query.getSingleResult();
    thread.setLastPost(post);
}
```

Post entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
@NamedQuery(name = "Post.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Post p")
public class Post implements Serializable, Comparable<Post> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int idpost;

    private String content;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_post")
    private Date datePost;

    private int downvotes;

    private int upvotes;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to PostVote
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
    private List<PostVote> postVotes;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Post
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "reply_to_post")
    private Post replyTo;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Post
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "replyTo")
    private List<Post> replies;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Thethread
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "threads_idthread")
    private Thethread thethread;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "users_username")
    private User user;

    @Transient
    private double confidenceScore;

    public Post() {
    }
```

Thethread Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "thethreads")
@NamedQuery(name = "Thethread.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM Thethread t")
public class Thethread implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int idthread;

    private String content;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_posted")
    private Date datePosted;

    // I could get this by scanning the Threadvotes and count the number of downvotes
   // But I thought it was better like this for ease and performance.
    private int downvotes;

    @Column(name = "hot_score")
    private int hotScore;

    @Column(name = "is_pol")
    private String isPol;

    private String title;

    private String type;

    private int upvotes;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Post
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "thethread")
    private List<Post> posts;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Category
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "categories_idcategory")
    private Category category;

    // UNI-directional many-to-one association to Post
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "last_post")
    private Post lastPost;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "posted_by")
    private User user;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to ThreadVote
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "thethread")
    private List<ThreadVote> threadVotes;
```

Comment: How are you assigning an ID to post, and have you checked its value in what gets returned from the createPostAndGiveItBack method?  The error states a referenced post is not from this persistence unit - you can change the cascade options to cascade merge on the lastPost relationship, or look up the post from the current EntityManager and use that to set the reference instead

Comment: @Chris the id is "0". Is there a best option in the 2 you told me ? Also I find it a bit weird that I have to look up for the entity I just persisted. Can't I just give it back directly from the function ? If not that's a shame and the lookup seems unnecessary. The thing is that I can't even look up the post because the id is unknown.

Comment: So you aren't setting an ID?  0 isn't considered a valid ID value by default in some providers.  Try setting a value or using ID generation.  If the ID is set, the provider will be able to use it to determine it is an existing instance (though possibly still unmanaged), and use it for the foreign key reference.

Comment: @Chris thanks I added @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) and it works. If you want to post it yourself I'll accept it as an answer. Sweet free karma! I actually already posted it and will delete if you do (I posted before reading your comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this to my entity ID:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

and it works.

Comment: I assume you are using a provider that does not interpret 0 as a valid ID by default, so it assumes your entity is new rather then an existing one.  You can change the provider settings to allow 0 etc values, but it is better to set the ID anyway

Comment: Actually the id generated after that wasn't 0. It was 30. I've absolutely no idea where the 0 id came from ?

Comment: Sorry, I was just adding info on why it was working.

Comment: @Chris Yes but I'm still not quiet sure I get it. When was the value 0 generated? Or is it the default value I'd get because it actually wasn't generated ?

Comment: It was 0 before you applied the GeneratedValue annotation.  When there is no GeneratedValue for the ID, the ID is left as 0 and the JPA provider later on assumes it is a new entity, causing an exception when it is referenced.  When you add the GeneratedValue, the ID is set and when the entity is found on merge later on, the provider can determine it is an existing entity that just isn't managed.

Comment: 0 is the default value for `int` type, no one was generating it